# What does this mean from logwatch? Kernel errors

Tags: apache, linux-kernel, kernel, report, server

I have received this in my daily logwatch report. I do not know what this means. I am concerned that my server is about to fail. I do not know enough to know what this data means.

```
     --------------------- Kernel Begin ------------------------ 


 WARNING:  Kernel Errors Present
            res 41/01:00:90:20:6c/00:00:1b:00:00/40 Emask 0x401 (device error) <F> ...:  4 Time(s)
            res 41/40:00:90:20:6c/00:00:1b:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F> ...:  1 Time(s)
            res 51/01:00:90:20:6c/00:00:1b:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error) ...:  6 Time(s)
            res 51/40:00:90:20:6c/00:00:1b:00:00/e0 Emask 0x9 (media error) ...:  7 Time(s)
    ata1.00: NCQ disabled due to excessive errors ...:  1 Time(s)
    ata1.00: error: { UNC } ...:  8 Time(s)
    sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocat ...:  2 Time(s)
    sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descr ...:  3 Time(s)

 3 Time(s):        1b 6c 20 90 
 2 Time(s):        72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
 1 Time(s):        72 03 13 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
 3 Time(s): Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
 13 Time(s): ata1.00: cmd 25/00:08:90:20:6c/00:00:1b:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
 5 Time(s): ata1.00: cmd 60/08:00:90:20:6c/00:00:1b:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
 18 Time(s): ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
 13 Time(s): ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
 5 Time(s): ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
 13 Time(s): ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
 5 Time(s): ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
 13 Time(s): ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
 5 Time(s): ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
 18 Time(s): ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
 18 Time(s): ata1: EH complete
 1 Time(s): sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Address mark not found for data field
 3 Time(s): sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 1b 6c 20 90 00 00 08 00
 3 Time(s): sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
 3 Time(s): sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code

 ---------------------- Kernel End -------------------------
```

Comment: Add the output of `smartctl -a /dev/sda`.

Answer (score 0):

ATA could be the hard disks. I'd suggest to test them if possible. Or check the filesystem.